# Extract node info with kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have this kotlin code:

```
private var wearNodesWithApp: Set<Node>? = emptySet()
private suspend fun findWearDevicesWithApp() {
    Log.d(TAG, "findWearDevicesWithApp()")
    try {
        val capabilityInfo = capabilityClient
            .getCapability(CAPABILITY_WEAR_APP, 
CapabilityClient.FILTER_ALL)
            .await()
        Log.d(TAG, "Capability request succeeded.")
        wearNodesWithApp = capabilityInfo.nodes
        Log.d(TAG, "Capable Nodes: $wearNodesWithApp")
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Capability request failed to return any results.")
    }
}

if (wearNodesWithApp!!.isNotEmpty()) {
                val node = wearNodesWithApp!!.first()
                Log.d(TAG, "Found node $node")
                result.success(node.id)
            } else result.success("Empty")
```

and it produces this output to the log:

Found node Node{Galaxy Watch4 (KBGZ), id=44147377, hops=1, isNearby=true}

I can extract the id as node.id, but how can I extract the first field, the watch type?

Comment: What is `wearNodesWithApp` you need to provide more information in order to get help.

Comment: Updated post, see above

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the API you are using, but you seem to be using Android's Wearable API. The [documentation for Node](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Node) states that there are 3 public methods - perhaps you need `getDisplayName()`.  There may be more undeclared fields - the String representation you list suggest there is a `hops` field also.

I would use a debugger and find out what the implementing class for `Node` is and then you could downcast and get access to more information easily, *BUT* at the risk of this information not being guaranteed if it is not listed in the public API.

Comment: Works great, thank you. I thought that by just typing node. in Android Studio, it would show me all available methods for node, but it doesn't. I should have followed the old rule "If everything else fails, read the documentation".  As you can imagine, my kotlin experience is quite limitied.